# Generic time range word

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, time

I am looking for a word that can replace idioms like *daily* or *monthly*, but has the same meaning, and it's **generic**.

By example, if I want to describe my pocket money, I can say I have a *daily amount*, or a *monthly amount* of money.

But how I can say I have a "Time span" amount of money, in a way that sounds intuitive?

Another example: Daily counter, hourly counter -> replaced by a "generic time-based" counter

Comment: *Interval counter* works for the counter example but not so well for the allowance.  Although perhaps *periodic allowance* might work for that one.

Comment: *Periodic allowance* fits just well in my expressions. If you can add it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [***Periodic***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/periodic) : *Happening or appearing at regular intervals*

appears to fit well- as in a *periodic allowance*.

For your counter example, [***Interval***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Interval)  may work- as in an *interval counter*.

Answer (score 2):

If an event occurs at fixed intervals, it is *regular*, as in ‘I have a regular income.’ You can also use the adverbial form as in ‘My income is paid regularly.’

(On a matter of terminology, *daily* and *monthly* are not idioms, because their meaning can be deduced solely from a knowledge of what the words mean.)

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to ask for a "time-span-ly" amount of money rather than a "time-span" amount, because that makes it clear that you are not asking for a noun.

You are asking for an adverb which describes how an event occurs, or an adjective which describes the event.

***Periodic*** fits the bill: the event occurs regularly after an (unspecified) period has elapsed.

Comment: Ah: it appears Jim and I think along the same lines.

Comment: Can periodic also be used when the intervals are not necessarily equal? Like to describe doing something, such as a revenue report, for a period - sometimes 3 months, sometimes 6, etc?